# How to select everything after a known part of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I'm looking to select everything to the right of a know part of an nvarchar data type.

ex: prov:default:/tag:Fab Floor/Fab Floor Test Alarm:/alm:Fab Floor Test Alarm

From these queried strings from a select * function, I only need the part of the string after 'alm:'. So I just need "Fab Floor Test Alarm".

I'm using Microsoft SQL server

Comment: SELECT select right(source, charindex('alm:', reverse(source)) - 1) from alarm_events where displaypath = 2. I found this code on here but I couldn'y get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
SELECT substring(v1,CHARINDEX('alm', v1)+4,1000) from test;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8771c/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @key varchar(10) = 'alm:',
    @value nvarchar(255) = 'prov:default:/tag:Fab Floor/Fab Floor Test Alarm:/alm:Fab Floor Test Alarm';

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING( @value, CHARINDEX( @key, @value ) + LEN( @key ), LEN( @value ) ) AS Remainder;
```

Returns

```
+----------------------+
|      Remainder       |
+----------------------+
| Fab Floor Test Alarm |
+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `right`:

```
select right(@mycol, len(@mycol) - charindex('alm:', @mycol) - 3) as alm
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bbaa86a705acb6905a6a2737f866be4b)**:

```
declare @mycol varchar(max) = 'prov:default:/tag:Fab Floor/Fab Floor Test Alarm:/alm:Fab Floor Test Alarm';
select right(@mycol, len(@mycol) - charindex('alm:', @mycol) - 3) as alm;
```

```
| alm                  |
| :------------------- |
| Fab Floor Test Alarm |
```